# Odd and Even Factors of a Perfect Square

Tags: square-numbers

If N is a perfect square, then we know that N has an odd number of distinct factors (because the square root gets counted twice).

However, can we prove that if N is a perfect square, then it will always have an odd number of odd factors and even number of even factors? If N is an odd perfect square, then each factor must be odd and therefore N has an odd number of odd factors and no even factors. However, I can't prove the same for even squares, since factors could be either odd or even, as long as one of the numbers in each pair is even..

Comment: I assume that by factor you mean divisor.

Comment: Yes, any number that divides N with 0 remainder.

Comment: The number of odd factors for a perfect square of the form $a^2\cdot 2^{2k}$ is the same as the number of odd factors of $a^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove your claim as follows: if $n$ is a square, for some prime numbers $p_1,\dots,p_m$ and some naturals $a_1,\dots,a_m$, you can write $$n=\Pi_{i=1}^m p_i^{2a_i}.$$
Since every divisor of $n$ has, as prime factors, a subset of $\{p_1,\dots,p_m\}$ with exponent no larger than $a_i$, $n$ has exactly $\Pi_{i=1}^m(2a_i+1)$ divisors. Now, let us suppose that $n$ is even, so (say) $p_1=2$. Then, to count odd divisors of $n$, you can simply ignore the factor $2$, which means that $n$ has $\Pi_{i=2}^m(2a_i+1)$ odd divisors, and this is an odd number (it is product of odd numbers).

Comment: Great, thanks very much.